# What kind of neat use cases exist for given/when?

Tags: perl, switch-statement

Perl 5.10 introduced a proper switch construct with `given/when` and it seems like a powerful tool.

Currently however, `perldoc perlsyn` lacks some good examples.

One case where I found it handy lately was for using it with file test operators:

```
given (-d "foo/bar/") {
    when (1) { ... } # defined is wrong as -d returns '' on a file.
    default { ... }
}
```

or alternatively:

```
given ("foo/bar/") {
    when (-d) { ... }
    default { ... }
}
```

For me, especially the first version looks better than an if-else construct or using the ternary operator, when depending on the outcome of the test I need to perform actions in both cases.

It made me wonder though, what else looks neat beyond the simple case of falling back to smart matching and avoiding overlong if-elsif-elsif-...-else structures?

I have a hunch that given/when makes it possible to be clever without losing clarity, but I don't have any good examples.

One thing that surprised me though, is that you can nest the construct aswell:

```
given ($filename) {
        when (-e) {
                when (-f) {
                        when (-z) { say "Empty file" }
                        default { say "Nonempty file" }
                }
                when (-d) {
                        when (-o) { say "Directory owned by me"}
                        default { say "Directory owned by someone else" }
                }
                default { say "Special" }
        }
        default { say "No such file or directory" } }
```

Comment: You may want to use `-f _`, `-z _`, `-d _`, and `-o _` to avoid calling `stat` on the same file `-e` called it on.  See [`perldoc -f -X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) for more information.

Comment: Indeed, it's usually a good idea to use the cached form. I didn't want to overcomplicate the example with unrelated things though. It rarely matters for performance anyway...

Comment: `-d` encompasses`-e` and `-f` encompasses`-e`, there is no reason to test `-e` unless `!-f && !-d`, it wouldn't change anything to just assume that in that case, if `-e`, then it's special.

Comment: @Axeman: while it's true that `-d` or `-f` encompasses `-e`, the point was to demonstrate given/when nesting and how it makes some things quite neat. I admit it's not the best example, that's why I asked for more :) Also, logically it makes sense to use both `-e` and `-f` and `-d` , because this is precisely the case where making a difference between "no such file" (any kind) and "special file" (socket, symlink, etc) falls out quite naturally from the construct.

Comment: There are several examples in the Smart Matching chapter of _Learning Perl_. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638949/strategies-to-handle-a-file-with-multiple-fixed-formats/3639674#3639674) to Zaid's question [Strategies to handle a file with multiple fixed formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638949/strategies-to-handle-a-file-with-multiple-fixed-formats), I ended up with a poor man's yacc whose main loop searched an array of regular expressions for the first match:

```
while (<>) {
  given($_) {
    when (@{[ map $pattern{$_}, @expect ]}) {}
    default {
      die "$0: line $.: expected " . join("|" => @expect) . "; got\n$_";
    }
  }
}
```

In another question, [David B wanted to match against multiple regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694322/how-to-match-against-multiple-regexes-in-perl), and [my answer uses smart matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694322/how-to-match-against-multiple-regexes-in-perl/3694382#3694382) to implicitly loop over the regexes:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use feature 'switch';

my @patterns = (
  qr/foo/,
  qr/bar/,
  qr/baz/,
);

for (qw/ blurfl bar quux foo baz /) {
  print "$_: ";
  given ($_) {
    when (@patterns) {
      print "hit!\n";
    }
    default {
      print "miss.\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `given` statement is a little annoying. Is there a reason that `while` can't be used as a topicalizer?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if below is a *neat use case* or just a tip of the hat to Perl's linguistic lineage :)

```
# things todo (or should have done!) at this time of the day:

given (TheTime->of_day) {

    when ('morning') {
        breakfast();
        make_packed_lunch() if $_->is_work_day;
    }

    lunch() when 'afternoon';

    when ('evening') {
        goto_pub() if $_->is_friday;
        dinner();
    }

    default { say "Should be sleeping if its " . $_->{dt}->ymd }
}
```

And if you view `$_` has *"it"* then it works particular well (IMHO).

The above works by [overloading](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html) the smart match operator which `given/when` rely on.  Here is how `TheTime` class could be written to make my example work:

```
{
    package TheTime;
    use DateTime;
    use overload '~~' => '_check_hour', fallback => 1;

    our %day_time = (
        morning   => [0..11],
        afternoon => [12..17],
        evening   => [18..23],
    );

    sub of_day {
        my $class = shift;
        bless {
            dt => DateTime->now,
        }, $class;
    }

    sub is_work_day { shift->{dt}->day_of_week ~~ [1..5] }
    sub is_friday   { shift->{dt}->day_of_week == 5      }

    sub _check_hour {
        my ($self, $greeting) = @_;
        $self->{dt}->hour ~~ $day_time{$greeting};
    } 
}
```

/I3az/

PS. Also see this blog post i did recently: [given/when – the Perl switch statement](http://transfixedbutnotdead.com/2010/08/30/givenwhen-the-perl-switch-statement/)