# Group input values using Perl

Tags: perl

I have decided to learn Perl and try to implement it for my assignment. Below is the flat file that has worker details.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Worker_id: 8CA980
Name: User1
Checkin_Time: Mon, 6 Jun 2016 09:09:28 
Address: Floor: 1
         Street: lane 2 
         City: Some city
         State: Some state
Access: 
/org/company/building_1
/org/company/building_2
/org/company/building_3
------------------------------------------------------------
Worker_id: 128AD6
Name: User2
Checkin_Time: Mon, 6 Jun 2016 10:09:28 
Address: Floor: 2
         Street: lane 3 
         City: Some city
         State: Some state
Access: 
/org/company/building_1
/org/company/building_2
------------------------------------------------------------
Worker_id: 699A0
Name: User1
Checkin_Time: Mon, 6 Jun 2016 08:15:00 
Address: Floor: 1
         Street: lane 3 
         City: Some city
         State: Some state
Access: 
/org/company/building_1
------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to parse and store the file values like,

```
@worker = <all the worker ids>
@name = <all the worker names>
@time = <all the worker check-in time>
@address = <worker address>
@access = <worker's access>
```

My code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
open (my $FH, '<', 'C:\\temp\\details.txt') or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
$/ = "*****"; # to change the default input separator from new line to some other
while (<$FH>) {
    @temp=split(/-{6,}/, $_);
}
close ($FH);
shift(@temp); #used shift as there was a empty array field

for ( $k=0; $k<@temp; $k++) {
    @temp1 = split(/\n/, $temp[$k]);
    @temp2 =  @temp1;   
    print "1st VALUE ===> $temp2[0]\n";
    print "2nd VALUE ===> $temp2[1]\n";
    print "3rd VALUE ===> $temp2[3]\n";
    ......
    .....
}
```

**Output is**

```
1st VALUE ===>
2nd VALUE ===> Worker_id: 8CA980
3rd VALUE ===> Checkin_Time: Mon, 6 Jun 2016 09:09:28
4th VALUE ===> Address: Floor: 1
5th VALUE ===>           Street: lane 2
6th VALUE ===>           City: Some city
7th VALUE ===>           State: Some state
8th VALUE ===> Access:

1st VALUE ===>
2nd VALUE ===> Worker_id: 128AD6
3rd VALUE ===> Checkin_Time: Mon, 6 Jun 2016 10:09:28
4th VALUE ===> Address: Floor: 2
5th VALUE ===>           Street: lane 3
6th VALUE ===>           City: Some city
7th VALUE ===>           State: Some state
8th VALUE ===> Access:

.........
```

Since I'm splitting values based on the new line,  Address and Access details **are not** getting stored as a single array element or value.I'm not quite getting the effective logic to organize the details to my above mentioned array format.

Yes , the dirty way would be splitting the values based on every unique id like - Worker_id then Name,Time so on but that would be absurd.

Could you please help me here with any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3638949/133939)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off - I wouldn't use separate arrays. A single data structure - an array of hashes - looks more sensible for your use case.

Secondly - `$/` is your friend. It's the record separator, and lets you iterate 'record by record' - and you have a clear one of `------`

And that looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

local $/ = "\n--";

my @records;

while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;
   my ($worker) = m/Worker_id: (.*)/;
   next unless $worker;
   my ($name)    = m/Name: (.*)/;
   my ($checkin) = m/Checkin_Time: (.*)/;

   #slightly more complicated patterns for multi-line fields
   #searches for lines, terminated by a word: at start of line,
   #end of record or ---- on a line. 
   my ($address) = m/Address: (.*?)(?:\n\w+:|\n---|\Z)/ms; #make capture non-greedy
   my ($access)  = m/Access:\s*\n(.*)(?:\n\w+:|\n--|\Z)/ms;
   $address =~ s/\s*\n\s*/, /g;
   push(
      @records,
      {  worker  => $worker,
         name    => $name,
         checkin => $checkin,
         access  => $access,
         address => $address
      }
   );

}

print Dumper \@records;

__DATA__
------------------------------------------------------------
Worker_id: 8CA980
Name: User1
Checkin_Time: Mon, 6 Jun 2016 09:09:28 
Address: Floor: 1
         Street: lane 2 
         City: Some city
         State: Some state
Access: 
/org/company/building_1
/org/company/building_2
/org/company/building_3
------------------------------------------------------------
Worker_id: 128AD6
Name: User2
Checkin_Time: Mon, 6 Jun 2016 10:09:28 
Address: Floor: 2
         Street: lane 3 
         City: Some city
         State: Some state
Access: 
/org/company/building_1
/org/company/building_2
------------------------------------------------------------
Worker_id: 699A0
Name: User1
Checkin_Time: Mon, 6 Jun 2016 08:15:00 
Address: Floor: 1
         Street: lane 3 
         City: Some city
         State: Some state
Access: 
/org/company/building_1
------------------------------------------------------------
```

It might also make sense to array-ify your 'access' field:

```
     access  => [split /\n/, $access],
```

But this gives you as output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'address' => 'Floor: 1, Street: lane 2, City: Some city, State: Some state, ',
            'access' => [
                          '/org/company/building_1',
                          '/org/company/building_2',
                          '/org/company/building_3'
                        ],
            'checkin' => 'Mon, 6 Jun 2016 09:09:28 ',
            'worker' => '8CA980',
            'name' => 'User1'
          },
          {
            'worker' => '128AD6',
            'address' => 'Floor: 2, Street: lane 3, City: Some city, State: Some state, ',
            'access' => [
                          '/org/company/building_1',
                          '/org/company/building_2'
                        ],
            'checkin' => 'Mon, 6 Jun 2016 10:09:28 ',
            'name' => 'User2'
          },
          {
            'name' => 'User1',
            'address' => 'Floor: 1, Street: lane 3, City: Some city, State: Some state, ',
            'access' => [
                          '/org/company/building_1'
                        ],
            'checkin' => 'Mon, 6 Jun 2016 08:15:00 ',
            'worker' => '699A0'
          }
        ];
```

Comment: This assumes that the keys come in a certain order. That's not a robust assumption.

Comment: For the multi-line ones? Yes, that's true. Edited with something a bit more robust.

Comment: @Sobrique : Thanks for the alternative (+1) and introducing me to array of hashes , (still a beginner.)

Comment: Those regex matches shouldn't have global `/g` modifiers.

Answer (score 3):

It's a shame, that format is *really* close to [YAML](http://yaml.org/). Then you could parse it with [YAML::XS](http://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::XS). This is what it would look like.

```
Worker_id: 8CA980
Name: User1
Checkin_Time: Mon, 6 Jun 2016 09:09:28 
Address:
    Floor: 1
    Street: lane 2 
    City: Some city
    State: Some state
Access: 
    - /org/company/building_1
    - /org/company/building_2
    - /org/company/building_3
```

---

You can write a little parser for your format. Your format has six sorts of lines.

- The record separator.
- A pair.
- A subpair.

  - Indented
  - Inline
- The start of a list.
- An element of a list.

To handle lists and subpairs you need to track the current key so you know what key to add to. Since there's state to track, I wrote a little WorkerParser class to hold the current worker and key. You could do without the object, it just makes it tider to hold onto state variables.

```
package WorkerParser;
use Moo;

has fh =>
  is        => 'ro',
  required  => 1;

has worker =>
  is        => 'ro',
  default   => sub { {} };

has key =>
  is        => 'rw';
```

I used [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo), a lightweight object system. You don't have to, it's just convenient. The object takes a filehandle to read from, and it can store the current key it's adding to, and the worker it's building. The worker defaults to an empty hash.

```
sub read_worker {
    my $self = shift;

    my $fh = $self->fh;
    while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        chomp $line;

        # Spotted a boundry
        if ( $line =~ /^-{6,}$/ ) {
            # If we parsed a worker, we're done.
            if ( $self->seen_worker ) {
                last;
            }
            # Otherwise this is the first line, keep going.
            else {
                next;
            }
        }
        else {
            $self->parseline($line);
        }
    }

    return $self->seen_worker ? $self->worker : ();
}
```

This is the basic read loop. If you see a `------` you're done unless you didn't read any worker info yet, in which case keep going. Otherwise, parse the line. This neatly separates parsing the worker from finding the beginning and end.

```
sub splitpair {
    my $self = shift;
    my $pair = shift;

    return split /\s*:\s*/, $pair, 2;
}
```

A method to ensure we always split pairs the same way.

```
sub parseline {
    my $self = shift;
    my $line = shift;

    my($key, $val) = $self->splitpair($line);

    # An element of a list.
    if( !defined $val ) {
        push @{$self->worker->{ +$self->key }}, $line;
    }
    # The start of a list.
    elsif( !length $val ) {
        $self->key($key);
        $self->worker->{ +$self->key } = [];
    }
    # Indented subpair.
    elsif( $key =~ s/^\s+// ) {
        $self->worker->{ +$self->key }{$key} = $val;
    }
    # Inline subpair.
    elsif( $val =~ /:/ ) {
        $self->key($key);
        my($subkey, $subval) = $self->splitpair($val);
        $self->worker->{$key}{$subkey} = $subval;
    }
    # A pair.
    else {
        $self->key($key);
        $self->worker->{$key} = $val;
    }

    return;
}
```

This is the meat. It checks for all the different possible lines and processes them. When a new key is encountered, it's remembered in `$self->key` so if the next line is a subkey or a list element it knows what key to add to.

The advantage of this approach over the others, is it fully parses the data while making no assumptions about what keys have what types of values, nor does it make any assumptions about the key order. This makes it robust and flexible.

```
my @workers;
while( my $worker = WorkerParser->new(fh => \*DATA)->read_worker ) {
    push @workers, $worker;
}
```

You use it by creating a WorkerParser and reading a worker. There's a new WorkerParser for each worker because it's safer to throw out a used object than the try and reset the state.

Comment: @Thanks Schwern, looks like a bit advanced to me (Perl beginner) but certainly something to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Using your input with the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

undef $/;
my $content = <ARGV>;
my @list1 = split(/-+\s+/,$content);
for (@list1) {
    if ($_) {
        my @list2 = split(/\n(?=\S)/,$_);
        print "element 1=$list2[0]\n\n";
        print "element 2=$list2[1]\n\n";
        print "element 3=$list2[2]\n\n";
        print "element 4=$list2[3]\n\n";
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
element 1=Worker_id: 8CA980

element 2=Name: User1

element 3=Checkin_Time: Mon, 6 Jun 2016 09:09:28

element 4=Address: Floor: 1
         Street: lane 2
         City: Some city
         State: Some state

element 1=Worker_id: 128AD6

element 2=Name: User2

element 3=Checkin_Time: Mon, 6 Jun 2016 10:09:28

element 4=Address: Floor: 2
         Street: lane 3
         City: Some city
         State: Some state

element 1=Worker_id: 699A0

element 2=Name: User1

element 3=Checkin_Time: Mon, 6 Jun 2016 08:15:00

element 4=Address: Floor: 1
         Street: lane 3
         City: Some city
         State: Some state
```

The key is the positive lookahead \n(?=\S) where I split on a new line followed by somthing that is not a white space.

Comment: What about Access?

Comment: @Essex Boy : Appreciate your input and an alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are many simpler ways but seeing as this is for an assignment, I just add some things to your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @temp;
my @temp1;
my $k;

my @workerIDs;
my @name;
my @CheckTimes;
my @Address;

open (my $FH, '<', 'C:\\temp\\somefile.txt') or die "Can't read file: $!\n";
$/ = "*****"; # to change the default input separator from new line to some other
while (<$FH>) {
@temp=split(/-{6,}/, $_);
}
close ($FH);
shift(@temp); #used shift as there was a empty array field

for ( $k=0; $k<@temp; $k++) {
@temp1 = split(/\n/, $temp[$k]);
    $temp1[1] =~ s/Worker_id://g;    # not needed, just throwing out the identifiers
    $temp1[2] =~ s/Name://g;
    $temp1[3] =~ s/Checkin_Time://g;
    $temp1[4] =~ s/Address://g;
    $temp1[4] =~ s/\s+//g;    # not needed, just throwing out whitespace.
    $temp1[5] =~ s/\s+//g;
    $temp1[6] =~ s/\s+//g;
    $temp1[7] =~ s/\s+//g;

push @workerIDs, "$temp1[1]\n";
push @name, "$temp1[2]\n";
push @CheckTimes, "$temp1[3]\n";
push @Address, "$temp1[4], $temp1[5], $temp1[6], $temp1[7]\n";

}

print "All WorkerIDs\n";
print @workerIDs;
print "All Names\n";
print @name;
print "All Check in Times\n";
print @CheckTimes;
print "All addresses\n";
print @Address;
```

where the results will be:

```
All WorkerIDs
8CA980
128AD6
699A0
All Names
User1
User2
User1
All Check in Times
Mon, 6 Jun 2016 09:09:28
Mon, 6 Jun 2016 10:09:28
Mon, 6 Jun 2016 08:15:00
All addresses
Floor:1, Street:lane2, City:Somecity, State:Somestate
Floor:2, Street:lane3, City:Somecity, State:Somestate
Floor:1, Street:lane3, City:Somecity, State:Somestate
```

Comment: This will break if the order of any of the items changes.

Comment: @schwern, Yes it will, but as mentioned there are easier and better ways, but I just amended his current code to push the values and assuming the file will always remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have used here regular expression to pull all worker id into an array. try similar way for all your inputs.

```
my @workerid=();
while ($seq =~ /Worker_id:\s*(\w+)/g)
{
push @workerid, $1;
}
```