# How can I match against multiple regexes in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I've seen this previous post, about matching against multiple regexes
[How can I match against multiple regexes in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694322/how-can-i-match-against-multiple-regexes-in-perl)

I'm looking for the fastest way to match all the values contained in an array against a very big file (500 MB).

The patterns are read from the stdin and may contain special characters that must be used in the regex (anchors, character classes etc). The match must happen when *all* the patterns are contained in the current row.

Currently I'm using a nested for cycle but I'm not very satisfied with the speed....

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: How have you confirmed that the IO speed of 500MB data is not the limiting factor?

Comment: As a simple optimisation, make sure your regexps which are most likely to fail are tested _first_.  That way you can skip on to the next record as quickly as possible when you spot a failure.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us some code and regexes, so we might have something to work with. Also, any information about how the input might look.

Comment: The file is read and then loaded in an array for faster access, so I think that it is not a bottleneck.

Comment: I will post the code, if I'm able to make it presentable ;-)

Comment: @user764169 You pull 500 megs into memory? Assuming you're searching line by line and only doing it once per file it is a huge waste of memory and it will have no effect on the performance of your search. In fact, it may slow things down as Perl allocates all that memory.

Comment: Are the things you're matching *patterns* or just strings?

Comment: Thanks Schwern, I put 500 megs into memory because it takes at least 5 seconds to read it, and I'm doing searches quite often.
The input is made of regular expressions (the search string plus special characters, anchors etc) for example ^word?\sAnotherWord

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try using grep?

```
while($line=<>) {
    if (scalar(grep($line=~/$_/,@regexps))==scalar(@regexps)) {
       # ... All matched
    }
}
```

Comment: or simply `if (!grep { !condition } @list) {...}`

Comment: thanks this code is simple and seems to work

use 5.014;

my @regexps= qw(foo? bar{2} [Rr]at ^this barren$); 
  
my $line='this food is rather barren';
    if (scalar(grep($line=~/$_/,@regexps))==scalar(@regexps)) {
say 'all matched'; 
    }

<br> else {say 'not all matched'}

Answer (score 8):

Try [Regexp::Assemble](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3a%3aAssemble) as suggested in the post you linked to and compare that to an iterative approach like `grep`.  Regexp::Assemble should produce the fastest solution since Perl can optimize the joined regexes rather than scanning the whole line for each one.  Since you don't know your input beforehand, ymmv.

Which version of Perl you're using will affect performance.  5.10 introduced a lot of optimizations for exactly this purpose (see "[tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)").  One of the biggest use cases is spam scanners like SpamAssassin which build a big regex of all the patterns they scan for, just like Regexp::Assemble.

Finally, since your input is so large, it may be worthwhile to assemble the regex into a file and then run `grep -P -f $regex_file $big_file`.  `-P` tells `grep` to use Perl compatible regular expressions.  The file is used to avoid shell quoting or command size limits.  `grep` may blow the doors off Perl.

In the end, you're going to have to do the benchmarking.

Comment: The problem with Regexp::Assemble is that returns "success" when it matches one condition, I need a match on all the conditions. I think that it is faster to continue to use the nested "for" cycle.
I'm using perl 5.14 (via the fantastic perlbrew).