# perl search sentence for keywords

Tags: perl, match, keyword

If I want to find a keyword in a sentence using Perl I have something like this:

```
foreach $line (@lines) 
{ 
   if ($line =~/keyword/) 
   {
      print $line;
   }
}
```

If I want to see if more keywords are in the sentence how should I change the matching?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I match against multiple regexes in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694322/how-can-i-match-against-multiple-regexes-in-perl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions. The easiest is to use something like `/keyword.*keyword/`.

When you want to count number of the keywords in a string (not simply check if there two keywords) you can do something like:

```
for(@lines){
    my $n = 0;
    $n++ while /(keyword)/g;
    print if ($n>2);
}
```

By the way, your code can be more concise:

```
for (@lines) {
  print if /keyword/;
}
```

That is the same.

Comment: `my $n = () = /keyword/g` is both tidier and more efficient

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process each match of all matches (*g* modifier):

```
my $number_of_matches = 0;

foreach $line (@lines) 
{ 
   while ( $line =~ m/keyword/g ) 
   {
      do_something_you_need();
      $number_of_matches++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my @words=map {split / /;} @lines;

foreach my $el(@keywords) {

    @match=grep {$el eq $_} @words;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to see if the sentence contains other (different) keywords, or do you want to check whether it contains the same keyword multiple times.

For the first, you can write

```
if ($line =~ /keyword1|keyword2|keyword3/) { ... }
```

and for the second, it looks like this

```
my $n = () = $line =~ /keyword/g;
```